# redirecting echo or printf output to variable which represents an std* stream in a bash script

Tags: bash

In perl, i usually do this:

```
...
if(exists($myLog))
{
    if( ! open($fhLog, '>>', $myLog))
    {
        print "[wrn] unable to open \"$myLog\", using stdout instead\n";
        $fhLog = *STDOUT;
    }
}
...
```

and then, throughout the script, i just use:

```
print $fhLog "\n[inf] started at $rndate\n";
```

regardless, knowing it'll either go to a file or `stdout`.

How can i `echo "text" > $someVar` in bash to achieve the same result?

**Edit**: bash 4.2 on RHEL7

Comment: Which version of bash?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy bash 4.2 on RHEL7, edited

Comment: That should be edited into the question, not the answer. :)

Comment: I didn't know/notice i could edit answers that are not my own, sorry. Also, i didn't know i need 6 chars to edit them (you have a typo on the last line). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming bash 4.1 or newer, you have automatic file descriptor validation, and the ability to redirect to a FD number in a variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in
  ""|[0-3].*|4.0*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.1 or newer is needed" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

logFd=2 ## default to logging to stderr

# if myLog variable exists, make logFd a file descriptor number open to it
[[ $myLog ]] && exec {logFd}>"$myLog"

echo "This will go to either the file or stderr" >&$logFd
```

There are two key parts to this:

- `exec {variableName}>filename` opens `filename` and assigns the file descriptor to the variable `variableName`. You can change the redirection operator (to `>>`, `<>`, etc) as appropriate.
- `>&$variableName` redirects to the file descriptor stored in `variableName`.

---

With older versions of bash, or for compatibility with POSIX sh, you'll want to use a fixed FD number:

```
#!/bin/sh
# here, we're using FD 3 for logging

if [ -n "$myLog" ]; then
  exec 3>"$myLog"
else
  exec 3>&2
fi

echo "This will go to either the file or stderr" >&3
```